# Encoding error while creating json object from MySQL database

Tags: json, encoding

I've a database in utf8-unicode format.
All I want to do is to change data from MySQL to json format.

This is my code.

```
<?php
define("DB_SERVER", "localhost");
define("DB_USER", "root");
define("DB_PASS", "");
define("DB_NAME", "book");

$connection = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
mysql_select_db('book', $connection);
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'", $connection);

if(mysqli_connect_errno()){
die( "Database connection failed" .
mysqli_connect_error().
"(" . mysqli_connect_errno() . ")"
);
}

$query = sprintf("SELECT * FROM list");
$result = mysql_query($query,$connection);
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
$out = "{\"books\":";
$out .= "[";
while($toshow = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
$Id = $toshow['id'];
$BookName = $toshow['book_name'];
$Author = $toshow['author'];
$AuthorOrder = $toshow['author_order'];
$Cat = $toshow['cat'];

$out .= "{";
$out .= "\"Book Name\" : \" " . $BookName . "\",";
$out .= "\"Author\" : \" " . $Author . "\",";
$out = rtrim($out,",");
$out .= "},";
}

$result = rtrim($out,",");
$result .= "]}";

echo ($result);
mysql_close($connection);

?>
```

But the output doesn't show in the right character encoding.
Any suggestion to get correct json output?

Comment: 1.: Oh god why - don't ever cobble together JSON by hand! Build an array and then `json_encode()` it. 2.: What *does* it show instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **array_push** with **json_encode**

```
<?php
define("DB_SERVER", "localhost");
define("DB_USER", "root");
define("DB_PASS", "");
define("DB_NAME", "book");

$connection = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
mysql_select_db('book', $connection);
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'", $connection);

if(mysqli_connect_errno()){
die( "Database connection failed" .
mysqli_connect_error().
"(" . mysqli_connect_errno() . ")"
);
}

$books = array();

$query      = sprintf("SELECT * FROM list");
$result     = mysql_query($query,$connection);
$num_rows   = mysql_num_rows($result);

while($toshow = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $Id             = $toshow['id'];
    $BookName       = $toshow['book_name'];
    $Author         = $toshow['author'];
    $AuthorOrder    = $toshow['author_order'];
    $Cat            = $toshow['cat'];

    array_push($books,
        array(
            "Id" => $Id,
            "Book Name" => $BookName,
            "Author" => $Author
        )
    );
}

$out = json_encode($books);

echo $out;
```